# using PcapDotNet, how do you extract the final payload?

Tags: c#, pcap.net

I have a C# application that uses PcapDotNet to sniff UDP packets with a capture filter.

Works fine, and there is a 6-byte payload but I can't seem to extract it as a byte array.  The UdpDatagram.Payload is a Datagram, with no method to extract the actual payload data.

Datagram has an ExtractPayload() but this gives an ILayer, which I can't seem to use to get to the payload.

How do you extract the ultimate payload from TcpDatagram or UdpDatagram?

Answer (score 4):

After PacketCommunicator.ReceivePacket() delivers the packet, then use Datagram.ToMemoryStream() to write to a local buffer:

```
Packet wpacket;

// wpacket = received packet

UdpDatagram udp = null;
TcpDatagram tcp = null;
Datagram datagram = null;

IpV4Datagram ip4 = wpacket.Ethernet.IpV4;
if (ip4.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.Udp)
{
    udp = ip4.Udp;
    datagram = udp.Payload;
}
if (ip4.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.Tcp)
{
    tcp = ip4.Tcp;
    datagram = tcp.Payload;
}
if (null != datagram)
{
    int payloadLength = datagram.Length;
    using (MemoryStream ms = datagram.ToMemoryStream())
    {
        byte[] rx_payload = new byte[payloadLength];
        ms.Read(rx_payload,0, payloadLength);
    }
}
```

Then rx_payload is available for parsing, display, or otherwise using the payload.